# How to use Oracle jdbc driver fixedString property in datasource.xml?

Tags: oc4j

I try configured fixedString property in the datasource.xml but doesnt work, this is in oc4j

```
<data-source 
location="jdbc/prueba" 
class="com.evermind.sql.DriverManagerDataSource" 
password="dagrof" max-connect-attempts="3" 
xa-location="jdbc/xa/prueba" 
ejb-location="jdbc/prueba" 
wait-timeout="1800" 
connection-driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
username="dagrof" 
min-connections="35" 
max-connections="300" 
url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@144.1.0.54:1521:nodox" 
inactivity-timeout="300" 
name="jdbc/prueba">

<property name="fixedString" value="true"/>

</data-source>
```

i Solved this problem in tomcat:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testsql" 
                        auth="Container"
                        type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
                        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
                        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@144.1.0.54:1521:nodox"
                        username="dandorrasc"
                        password="dandorrasc" 
                        maxActive="8"
                        maxIdle="4"
   connectionProperties="fixedString=true;"
/>
```

but here doesnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug that is corrected in version 10.1.2.3 OAS

Bug 10222534: UNABLE TO SET FIXEDSTRING PROPERTY IN DATASOURCE